# Show that $0<f(x)=\sup\{ f_{\lambda} (x) : \lambda \in \Gamma \}$ is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\{ f_{\lambda}  : \lambda \in \Gamma \}$ a family of seminorms

Show that $0<f(x)=\sup \{ f_{\lambda}(x)  : \lambda \in \Gamma \}$  for $x\in V $ with $x \neq 0 $ is a norm

I did if $f(x)=0$ then $\sup\{ f_{\lambda}(x)  : \lambda \in \Gamma \}=0$ but how $f_{\lambda}$ is not negative for all $\lambda \in \Gamma$ then $f_{\lambda}(x)=0$

and if $x\neq 0 $ then $f_{\lambda}(x)>0$ which is a contradiction then $x=0 $ then $f$ is a norm is right?

Comment: Just observe that $x\neq0\implies f(x)\neq0$ is logically equivalent to $f(x)=0\implies x=0$

Answer (score 1):

If $x,v\in V$ then for all $\lambda\in\Gamma$, $f_\lambda(x+y)\leqslant f_\lambda(x)+f_\lambda(y)$, so taking supremums yields
$$
f(x+y) = \sup_{\lambda\in\Gamma} f_\lambda(x+y) \leqslant \sup_{\lambda\in\Gamma}f_\lambda(x)+\sup_{\lambda\in\Gamma}f_\lambda(y) = f(x) + f(y).
$$
If $c$ is a scalar then
$$
f(cx) = \sup_{\lambda\in\Gamma}f_\lambda (cx) = |c|\sup_{\lambda\in\Gamma}f_\lambda (x) = |c|f(x).
$$
Positive definiteness follows immediately from the assumption that $f(x)>0$ for $x\ne 0$.